# JQuery/javascript doubleclick=do something on each div from foreach() php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have this PHP file:

```
foreach($allfiles as $file) {
    echo '<div class="file" id="file' . $file->id . '">';
        echo '<div id="checkbox"><a href="delete?file=' . $file->id . '" class="delete"><img src="images/delete.png" width="15" height="15"></img></a></div>';
        echo '<div id="filename">'. $file->name . '</div>';
        echo '<div id="size">| '. $file->size . ' </div>';
        echo '<div id="created">'. $file->created . '</div>';
        echo '<div id="download"><a href="download?' . $file->id . '"><img src="images/download.png" width="18" height="18"></img></a></div>';
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
    <script>
        var id = <?php echo $file->id; ?>
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

and this JS file

```
$('#file' + id).dblclick(function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

What I'm trying to do is that when div "file" + the file id is clicked, it will alert "1" (or open the file).
The problem is that now it only alerts 1 when I doubleclick the last div I have, while it is supposed to be done on all of them.
Is there a solution like foreach div called file + something do ? when doubleclicked.

Sorry if this was very unclear :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data-*` prefixed custom attribute like

```
echo '<div class="file" data-id="' . $file->id . '">';
```

Bind your event using the common class and then fetch `data-id`using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$('.file').on('dblclick', function() {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Comment: Use `on('dblclick'` inst3ad of `dblclick`. It is faster.